# Comparing Vector in Java

Tags: java, vector

Suppose, I have a vector with following values in it

```
id = 100
latitude = 2 .33
longitude = 4.55

id = 200
latitude = 1.00
longitude = 3.00

id = 300
latitude = 2.33
longitude = 4.55
```

and I have following variables

```
int item = 10;
double x = 2.33;
double y = 4.55
```

1.) Now, I want to compare the values of 2 variables (x,y) with that of (latitude,Longitude) in the vector.

2.) If (x,y) value is equal to (latitude,Longitude) then I add value of item variable to the vector

My logic to achieve it is as follows

```
Vector al;
int size = al.size() //need to adjust the size as and when i add/remove items from al

for(int i=0;i<sz-1;i++)
{
  if(al.get(i).getClass().equals(Double.TYPE)) //Need to ignore id in Vector

   if(a.get(i)==x & a.get(i+1)==y)
    {
      //add the sensor id at i-2 and adjust the size of vector
    }
   else {
          //remove the items 200,1.00,3.00
          // adjust the size of vector
        }
```

But the above code is not giving me expected result.Can anybody provide me with working code to get the final output as follows

```
10,100,2.33,4.55
10,300,2.33,4.55
```

Note that contents 200,1.00,3.00 are not present in the expected o/p, 'coz value of (x,y) does not match with (latitude, longitude)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to solve the above problem. I am including code snippet

```
public void manip() {

    System.out.println("ArratList (Before) :" + Array);
    int sz = Array.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < sz - 1; i++) {
        Object o = Array.get(i);
        if (o instanceof Double) {
            if (Array.get(i).equals(x) & Array.get(i + 1).equals(y)) {
                if (i == 1) {

                    Array.add(0, item);
                } else {

                    Array.add(i - 1, item);
                }
                i = i + 3;
            } else {
                Array.remove(i - 1);
                Array.remove(i - 1);
                Array.remove(i - 1);
                i = i - 1;
            }
            sz = Array.size();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("ArratList (After) :" + Array);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `==` with `Double` objects. You are comparing them to be the **same instance, not to have the same value**.

With doubles, it is best to compare the difference to be below a certain threshold, as there could be different rounding artifacts.

Answer (score 3):

I think the use of bitwise AND is a mistake:

```
if(a.get(i)==x & a.get(i+1)==y)
```

use boolean AND:

```
if(a.get(i)==x && a.get(i+1)==y)
```

See [Anony-Mousse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060350/anony-mousse) answer relating to use of `==` with objects.

Comment: Note that a single `&` [isn't necessarily a "bitwise" operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-in-and). It can apply to booleans too, so wouldn't cause a problem here (though there is no reason to use it).

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the vector is storing ids at position 0, 3, ..., (0 mod 3), you should start your loop at i = 1 and increment by 3 each time:

```
for(int i=1;i<sz;i+=3)
```

Then you don't have to check that the item is a double

Answer (score 0):

When working with collection I would say: use Apache Collections - They have a very useful  CollectionUtils utility object:

http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html