# Java Logical 'AND' vs 'OR' Short-Circuiting Consistency

Tags: java, evaluation, logical-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference in & and &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-in-and)

I've read several tutorials and answer regarding short circuit operations in java and I'm still not quite understanding the difference in how java handles short circuiting for a double vertical pipe vs a double ampersand. For instance ...

> **Why does the logical AND short circuit evaluation fail?**

Citing the JSL 15.23. Conditional-And Operator &&

> `The conditional-and operator && is like & (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is true.`

```
public static void main( String... args ) {


    int a = 1;

    int b = 2;

    // Okay. Prints
    if( a == 1 | b == 3 ) {

        System.out.println( "Comparison via |" + "\na is " + a + "\nb is " + b );

    }

    // Okay. Prints
    if( a == 1 || b == 3 ) {

        System.out.println( "Comparison via ||" + "\na is " + a + "\nb is " + b );

    }

    // Okay. Does not print
    if( a == 1 & b == 3 ) {

        System.out.println( "Comparison via &" + "\na is " + a + "\nb is " + b );

    }

    // I don't understand. Shouldn't the Short Circuit succeed since the left side of the equation equals 1?
    if( a == 1 && b == 3 ) {

        System.out.println( "Comparison via &&" + "\na is " + a + "\nb is " + b );

    }

}
```

Comment: `|` and `&` are bitwise or/and operators; they're different from `||` and `&&`, which are the logical or/and operators.

Comment: I know I don't get number four though ... I'm lost there :-)

Comment: @NullUserException: Well, they're different in terms of short-circuiting - but the JLS defines one in terms of the other... see my answer. (Note that for `boolean` operands, they're still logical operators...)

Comment: @NullUserException `|` and `&` are also non-short-circuiting logical or and and operators.

Comment: For short-circuiting to work in #4 it would have to fail the a==1 test.  In that case it can conclude that the result of the && is false because false&&anything is false.
In test 2 short-ciruiting is occuring but that doesn't change the result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I don't understand. Shouldn't the Short Circuit succeed since the left side of the equation equals 1?

No, absolutely not. The point of `&&` is that the result is only `true` if the left *and* the right operands are `true`; the short-circuiting means that the right operand isn't evaluated if the left operand is `false`, because the answer is known at that point.

You should read sections [15.23](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23) and [15.24](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24) of the JLS for more details:

> The conditional-and operator && is like & (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is true.
>
> The conditional-or operator || operator is like | (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is false.

Comment: Thank you ... Got it ...  There is a difference ... and I will have to practice this to make it 'concrete' :-)

Answer (score 2):

When used with `boolean`s, the bitwise operators (`|` and `&`) are *similar* to the logical operators (`||` and `&&`) except that:

- In the case of `&&`, if the first argument is `false` the second is left unevaluated, because the *whole* expression must then be `false`. For `&`, both arguments are evaluated regardless.
- In the case of `||`, if the first argument is `true` the second is left unevaluated, because the *whole* expression must then be `true`. For `|`, both arguments are evaluated regardless.

This is what we mean by "short-circuiting": the process of leaving the second argument unevaluated because in certain cases we can know the value of the *whole* expression just from the value of the first argument.

---

Now you ask why the following expression is `false`: **`a == 1 && b == 3`**. Well, short-circuiting has nothing to do with it; `a = 1` and `b = 2`, so the statement `"a is 1 and b is 2` is evidently `false`, since `b` is not `2`.

Comment: **tl;dr**: Bitwise (`|` and `&`) operators evaluate both arguments regardless; logical operators (`||` and `&&`) *can* (but don't always) short circuit.

Comment: @NullUserException When do they not short circuit?

Comment: In the OP's example it didn't short circuit.

Comment: @NullUserException Yes of course because `a == 1` was `true` - the logical operators short-circuit whenever they *can* short circuit.

Comment: @NullUserException I misunderstood, thinking you were implying that there were cases where the logical operators didn't short-circuit even when they could - my mistake. Anyway, glad we're on the same page finally!

Answer (score 1):

The logical operators `||` and `&&` short-circuit if the result is determined after evaluating the first operand. For `||` that is the case if the first operand evaluates to `true`, for `&&`, if it evaluates to `false`.

If the first operand of `||` is `false`, it can still yield an overall result of `true` if the second operand is `true`. Similarly, if the first operand of `&&` is `true`, it can still evaluate to `false` if the second operand is `false`.

In Java, the operators `|` and `&` are not only bitwise operators (when applied to integer arguments), but also non-short-circuiting logical operators that evaluate both operands regardless of the value of the first.

Answer (score 1):

Both & and && require both sides to be true, so the code is behaving as expected.

The only difference is that & executes both sides, but && executes only the first if it is false, because the right side would the  be irrelevant to the final result.

The effect of this is important for code like

```
if (obj == null || obj.isSomthing())
```

would throw an NPE if you used | and obj was null.

Comment: This is one slippery fish ... ;-)

Comment: After changing the vars to booleans this became crystal clear :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if( a == 1 && b == 3 ) {
   System.out.println( "Comparison via &&" + "\na is " + a + "\nb is " + b );
}
```

First it checks, if `a == 1` this is true, so it has to go on and check if `b == 3`, this is not true, so `true && false` is `false` and you don't get output.

if you had

```
if( b == 3 && a == 1 ) {
       System.out.println( "Comparison via &&" + "\na is " + a + "\nb is " + b );
}
```

it would first check if `b == 3` and since that's not the case don't even bother looking at `a == 1` because `false && whatever` is always `false`, not matter what `whatever` is.

Does that answer your question?