# Is there any example where & would be useful in an if statement than &&

Tags: java

I was reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-in-and) i am wondering why anyone would care to test the second condition if the first is false

eg:

```
boolean a =false;
if(a && b) //do soemthing
```

Why would you test if b is false?

Comment: `&` is the bitwise AND, there's a substantial difference between `&` and `&&`

Answer (score 1):

Single `&` is a bitwise operator, so that's what you use it for. For instance, if you wanted to check if a bit is set:

```
unsigned int bit = 4;
if (bit & value) {
    //third lowest bit is set
}
```

This happens a lot in C library functions. It's really useful if you're conserving memory and using individual bits rather than separate variables.

EDIT: I misread the post a bit. I see the context you are talking about now. So to agree with the others, only if b has a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

It could make sense if for example you have a function which does something that you want to get fired, regardless of what the first value is.

```
if( a & _checkForB())
```

Answer (score 0):

The only case I can think of is where the evaluation of the second has some desirable side effect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the actual use, but sometimes you have code acrobatics such as

```
string s;
if((s = reader.read()))
{
    doStuff
}
```

and i suppose you can use the `&`, if you had multiple things in your condition that did stuff.

Answer (score 0):

> Why would you test if b is false?

I guess you mean:

Why would you test b if a is false?

E.g. if b has a side effect. Though you probably have a design issue in this case.

In practice, "&" is not used for booleans except maybe "&=".