# Explain if (++value % 2 == 0 && ++count < limit) in java

Tags: java, operator-precedence

```
public class AndOperator {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int value = 8;
        int count = 10;
        int limit = 11;

        if (++value % 2 == 0 && ++count < limit) {
            System.out.println("here");
            System.out.println(value);
            System.out.println(count);
        } else{
            System.out.println("there");
            System.out.println(value);
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}
```

i am getting output as

```
there
9
10
```

explain how count is 10....?

Answer (score 15):

`&&` is [short-circuit operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html). It will only evaluate the 2nd expression if the 1st expression evaluates to true.

Since `++value % 2 == 0` is false, hence it doesn't evaluate the 2nd expression, and thus doesn't increment `count`.

Answer (score 4):

`++value` = 9 so `++value % 2 == 0` is `false` so `++count < limit` is not evaluated.

This is called *Short circuit evaluation*. See the wikipedia page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `&&`(logical and) operator.

> logical and evaluate second condition only if first condition is evaluated to true

Here in your code first condition `++value % 2 == 0` is evaluated to `false`,so second condition `++count < limit` won't be evaluated.
If you want to execute `++count < limit` also use `&`.
more information read [Difference between & and &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-in-and)

Comment: @down voter could you explain reason so that I can correct my mistake.?

Answer (score 2):

Because ++value % 2 == 0 is false, thus it won't return the first statement. The reason ++value % 2 is false is because value is incremented by one before the mod operator is evaluated. So ++value % 2 is 9 % 2 which != 0.