# Why does (i<=j && j<=i && i!=j) evaluate to TRUE?

Tags: java

I have written a piece of Java code which is running in an infinite loop.

Below is the code:

```
public class TestProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer i = new Integer(0);
        Integer j = new Integer(0);

        while(i<=j && j<=i && i!=j){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, while seeing the condition in the `while` loop, at first it looks like that program will not go inside the `while` loop. But actually it is an infinite loop and keeps printing the value.

What is happening here?

Comment: Simple answer is `i<=j && j<=i && i!=j` this condition always evaluates to true. Just take a piece of paper and evaluate you will catch it :)

Comment: The way you are creating integer is incorrect.  Use 'compareTo'

Comment: If you never change `i` or `j`, when would you expect the loop to terminate?

Comment: @PradeepSimha For simple int values, this would always yield *false*. From `i<=j` and `j<=i` you can conclude, that `i == j`, which contradicts the last term. Thus the whole expression evaluates to false and the while would not be entered. Key point is the object identity here!

Comment: Is there a **point** to the Integer cache?

Comment: As an aside, this is puzzle 32 in the book Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases.

Comment: @nachokk By that you mean `Integer.valueOf()`, right? AFAIK, `compareTo()` does not return `Integer`s, but rather `int`s, and is for _comparing_, not obtaining instances.

Comment: @AJMansfield They are 2 sentences may be my english is not good. First sentence is what you point. Second sentence `compareTo` to compare objects with their natural order rather than using `i<=j` etc..

Comment: possible duplicate of [When comparing two Integers in Java does auto-unboxing occur?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/when-comparing-two-integers-in-java-does-auto-unboxing-occur)

Comment: Another way of framing this puzzle "In Java, will the condition i<=j && j<=i && i!=j ever evaluate to true?"

Answer (score 189, accepted):

- `i <= j` is evaluated to `true`, because auto unboxing happens for int
  comparisons and then both `i` and `j` hold the default value, `0`.
- `j <= i` is evaluated to `true` because of the above reason.
- `i != j` is evaluated to `true`, because both `i` and `j` are
  different objects. And while comparing objects, there isn't any need of
  auto unboxing.

All the conditions are true, and you are not changing `i` and `j` in loop, so it is running infinitely.

Comment: can you please explain, why != is checking for the memory index of reference objects and <= is checking for the un-boxed value of Integer ??.. why there is such difference between these operator ?

Comment: @PunithRaj < & > operators work on primitives and not on objects, hence the auto unboxing happens for these operators. But == and != operators can be used for objects comparison also so no need of unboxing here, hence objects are compared.

Comment: Ah, the hidden dangers of implicit boxing/unboxing!!

Comment: Stack Overflow should just add a new tag, "Auto-unboxing was the biggest mistake ever made in Java".  :-). Except for writers of the Java Puzzler books.  Use it to tag questions like these.

Comment: @user949300 It's not a mistake, it's useful in many contexts.

Comment: @arshajii  other than saving typing "intValue()", where have you found unboxing to be  very useful?  I mainly find it confusing.  For the record, I think autoboxing is o.k. and often very useful.

Comment: note that `Integer.valueOf(0) == Integer.valueOf(0)` is always evaluated to true because in this case the same object is returned (see IntegerCache http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.IntegerCache)

Comment: @user949300 There are times when you explicitly need to use the wrapper classes instead of primitives (e.g. if you need to support a `null` value). In such cases, auto unboxing allows you to use these variables with regular arithmetic operations, e.g. `a + b` where `a` and `b` are `Integer`s. I find this to be convenient.

Comment: @arshajii If you need to support a null value, then doing math "conveniently" is a poor idea.

Comment: @VitaliiFedorenko the spec only guarantees this behaviour for numbers in range `[128,-127]`, so don't count on it in general http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29

Comment: @pwes right, that's what the [line 576](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#576) says: `Integer cache[] = new Integer[-(-128) + 127 + 1];`

Comment: @VitaliiFedorenko you must distinguish between the code and the docs. The implementation is a subject to change, the java.lang API, and hence the JavaDocs, is the official part of Java standard.

Comment: A classic example of C# really helping you dodge insanity like this with structs, overriding of Equals and operator overloading. You'd have to go way out of your way to end up in this confused place Java leaves you.

Comment: @user949300 I'd rather say the big mistake here is that == (or !=, for that matter) does not call equals. If object identity was a different operator, that wouldn't be as confusing as well.

Answer (score 41):

Because you are comparing

- `0 < = 0 (true) // unboxing`
- `0 > = 0 (true) // unboxing`
- `reference != secondReference (true)` as you are creating objects, not a primitive comparison. So it evaluates to *`while(true) { // Never ending loop }`*.

Comment: Ohh! hidden Dragon of auto UNBOXING ... Good Explanation .

Answer (score 17):

The integer objects are different. It is different from the basic int type.

See this answer: [How to properly compare two Integers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/when-comparing-two-integers-in-java-does-auto-unboxing-occur)

The `i != j` part is true, which you were expecting to be false.

Comment: While true, it doesn't matter here nor does it answer the question.

Comment: @Kon: In fact this is the answer. Conditions #1 and #2 evaluate to `true` because of autoboxing. In case of #3 autoboxing does not apply and comparison takes place on object (memory location) level.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different cases which we have to understand first,

case 1:

```
        Integer i = new Integer(10);
        Integer j = new Integer(10);

        System.out.println((i<=j && j<=i && i!=j));
        System.out.println(i!=j);
```

case 2:

```
        Integer i = 10;
        Integer j = 10;

        System.out.println((i<=j && j<=i && i==j));
        System.out.println(i==j);
```

both are different, as

in case 1: `i!=j` will be `true` because both referencing to two different object in heap and can't be same. But

in case 2: `i==j` will be `true` because both 10 are integer literals and Java maintains `pool for Integer literals` which have value `(-128 <= X <= 127)`. So, in this case 10<=127 results true, So both will have reference to same object.

Answer (score 1):

The loop is not ending because your condition is true( i != j is true because there are 2 different objects, use Integer.valueOf instead) and inside the loop the values are not changing so your condition remains true forever.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the reason is that both 'i' and 'j' are objects, and object comparison is not the same as object reference comparison. Please consider using !i.equals(j) instead of i!=j

Answer (score 1):

The integer objects are different. It is different from the basic int type.
so you can just do like that. what you do it's just compare the object and of course the result is true.

Answer (score 1):

> Integer a = new Integer(0);
>   Integer b = new Integer(0);

The <= and >= comparisons will use the unboxed value 0, while the != will compare the references and will succeed since they are different objects.

Even this will also works i,e

> Integer a = 1000; Integer b = 1000;

but this doesnot :

> Integer a = 100; Integer b = 100;

The reason is because Integer internally uses caching for Integer objects between -128 and 127 and return instances from that cache for the range it covers. I am not sure but I guess you can also change its maximum value in package "java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high".

For better understanding check url : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching

Answer (score 0):

The program keeps on displaying the same value of `i` because you aren't incrementing or decrementing either the value of `i` or `j`. The condition in the for always keeps evaluating to true, so it is an infinite loop.

Comment: I think the question was more about the `i!=j` part which surprisingly evaluates to true and not the `<=` comparisons.

Answer (score -3):

you have to know its a bit different in && this and this & when you use && then when first condition is true then it check second condition if its false then it not checked third condition  because in & operator if one condition is false all of the statement is false if use || then if  it see true then it return true in your code because i and j is equal first and second condition are true then in third condition it will be false because they are equal  and while condition is false .

Comment: i don't know why my answer get mines value because my answer is true see this link its true then before get mines to my answer read more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-between-and