# How do I listen to only numeric keypresses?

Tags: java, keylistener

I want to write a key listener to listen for only numeric keys. How can I achieve this?

Here's what I've tried:

```
if (  e.getKeyCode() > 96 & e.getKeyCode() < 106
   || e.getKeyCode() > 47 & e.getKeyCode() < 58)
{
    // do something
}
```

What is the problem in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() >= 96 && e.getKeyCode() <= 105 || e.getKeyCode() >= 48 && e.getKeyCode() <= 57){
     // do something
}
```

Note the difference between [& and &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-between-and), also fixed the keycode ranges.