# Null pointer Exception in array List

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
list1=object.getsomeFiles();
```

`getsomeFiles()` contains some code which returns file names if exists or returns `null`

I checked with

```
if(list1!=null&&!list1.isEmpty())
```

but still `NullPointerException` is thrown.

When I did debugging I found that list1 holds `null` value.

Comment: After edit still `NPE` then your `object` is `null`. Check that you have valid reference in `object` on which you are calling `getsomeFiles()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the answers explained about `&` and `&&` very well.

But, after you edit your are still getting `NullPointerException` then problem is your **`object` is `null` on which you are calling `getsomeFiles()` method.**

```
list1=object.getsomeFiles();
       ↑ //null
```

In you code if you have

```
SomeFileClass object; //here object is null
```

Make sure that `object` is initialized like:

```
object = new SomeFileClass();
```

Or initialize at object creation

```
SomeFileClass object = new SomeFileClass();
```

---

From Java docs [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

Thrown when an application attempts to use `null` in a case where an object is required. These include:

- **Calling the instance method of a null object.**
- Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
- Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
- Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
- Throwing null as if it were a `Throwable` value.

Answer (score 3):

`&` will break the [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), use `&&` instead.

---

**Explanation**:

If you have:

```
if(a() & b())
```

Then **both** `a` and `b` will be performed, and the final result will be evaluated.

But if you have:

```
if(a() && b())
```

Then if `a()` is `false`, `b()` **won't** be reached.

Answer (score 2):

The "object" instance is null.

```
ArrayList<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
if(Object!=null){
    list1=object.getsomeFiles();
    if(list1!=null&&!list1.isEmpty()){
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change  `if(list1!=null&!list1.isEmpty())` in to  `if(list1!=null&&!list1.isEmpty())`

`short-circuit(like &&)`, don't evaluate the right hand side if it that doesn't necessary. As an example if && left hand side is false no need to evaluate right hand side one. In other way || if left is true no need to evaluate right hand side one. So if `list` is `null` rest of the part will not evaluate.

`non-short(like &)` evaluvate both side always.So you will get `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, if you used `&` to check two conditions, both statements get evaluated regardless of first statement being `true` or `false`.  If first one is `false`, the evaluating the second one results in a `NullPointerException`. To overcome this, you should you the `&&` operator. It will evaluate the second expression only if first is true, that is only if `list1` is not `null`.

Therefore, the correct condition inside the if should be

```
list1 != null && !list1.isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered by the other guys change `&` to `&&`.

The problem is due to the difference between `&` and `&&`.

eg.

```
 if (A==B && B==C)
```

first jvm evaluates A==B if false exit with false

```
 if (A==B & B==C)
```

first JVM evaluates `A==B` if false or true JVM evaluates also `B==C`

it is a Java specification called *"short-circuited"*

See [Difference between & and &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-between-and)

Answer (score 0):

Replace single `&` with double `&&` in your `if` condition

This

```
if(list1!=null&!list1.isEmpty())
```

should be

```
if(list1!=null && !list1.isEmpty())
```

`&&` is logical and i.e. true && true is true and everything else is false. 
whereas `&` is bitwise and.

Answer (score 0):

use `&&` instead of `&`

```
if(list1!=null && !list1.isEmpty())
```