# Java Boolean Check

Tags: java, boolean

I work on Java 8 and I have a simple issue that I have not figured out.

I have a 3 methods which are validating the data from db and returning true or false based on whether they got a row or not. The tricky part is, even if I know that the first part
is returning false, I still want it to check for the other two methods. I have written my code like this :

```
boolean flag = true;

flag = flag && validateMethod1();
flag = flag && validateMethod2();
flag = flag && validateMethod3();

return flag;
```

The issue is, when validateMethod1() returns false, it is not calling validateMethod2(). Can someone explan why ?
I tried this :

```
 boolean flag = true;

    flag = flag & validateMethod1();
    flag = flag & validateMethod2();
    flag = flag & validateMethod3();

    return flag;
```

Still face the same issue.

Comment: Because and can never be true, if one operator is false.

Comment: but why you want to do that, `&&` means if one `false` then result is `false`

Comment: @Mritunjay Maybe `validateMethod2` and `validateMethod3` have side effects

Comment: Actually my requirement is to modify the db in case of false. And so I want to check in all the methods.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-between-and

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&&` is a short circuited AND operator. It doesn't evaluate the second operand if the first operand is evaluated to `false`.

In order to evaluate all the operands, use the non-short-circuit version of the AND operator :

```
return validateMethod1() & validateMethod2() & validateMethod3();
```

As you can see, your logic can be reduced to a single line of code.

Comment: on one hand yes, on the other something went wrong when designing the code.

Comment: what if I wanna have the old format ? Should I save it in seperate boolean variables and then use '&'?

Comment: @AnkushBhan You can use your original code and just replace `&&` with `&`, but it doesn't look very elegant. Using separate boolean variables will also work (but then you can either use `&` or `&&`, since the AND operator will only be applied after the 3 methods are executed).

Comment: @Eran I understand, but what if I have more than 25 such methods and for each method I wanna check the boolean result and move to the next one ?BTW i used the '&' instead of '&&'. Still gives the same problem

Comment: @AnkushBhan `&` should work fine. Try to add print statements to the validation methods and you'll see all of them are executed (unless some exception is thrown).

Answer (score 2):

Java uses sort-circuit evaluation of expressions - i.e. as soon as it knows for sure the result will be `false`, it stops the evaluation.

Since your expression is a conjunction, once `flag` is found to be false, it is clear the whole expression will be false.

One way around it (quite verbose) is:

```
boolean flag1 = validateMethod1();
boolean flag2 = validateMethod2();
boolean flag3 = validateMethod3();
return flag1 && flag2 && flag3;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using short circuit `&&` instead of `&`, which leads to check only first argument in this case, when this argument is `false`.

The `&` operator, when used as logical operator, always evaluate both sides.