# Java & and && operators troubles

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, boolean, operator-keyword

I'm trying to figure out why `&` operator throws an exception and suspends my program but when I use `&&` operator the program works with no errors. 

Here is the portion of the code:

- `books` is an arraylist of objects `Book`.
- `areYouBook` returns `true` if the book's ISBN I'm looking for matches `a`.
- The method `findBook` checks if I already have the book in the arraylist. When the method returns `null`, it means I have to create the book and add it to the `ArrayList`.

Thank you very much for your help!

```
public Book findBook(int a){
    int i=0;
    while((i<(books.size()))&!((books.get(i)).areYouBook(a)))
      i++;
    if(i<(books.size())) 
      return books.get(i);
    else
      return null;
}
```

Comment: Because `&` is the [bitwise AND operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), not the logical AND.

Comment: Also, I highly recommend you use braces `{}` for your blocks (`while`, `if`, `else`) all the time and indent your code properly. This is not only hard to read and understand, it is bound to execute in ways that you did not intend.

Comment: [Difference between & and &&](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-between-and)

Comment: @domdom not for boolean operands. `&` *is* the [logical and operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2). `&&` is the conditional and operator.

Comment: @AndyTurner I really didn't expect to learn something that fundamental today (especially because I thought I knew all about this). I feel a bit embarrassed and quite enlightened. Thanks!

Comment: @domdom watch out, you're swimming in pedant-infested waters ;)

Comment: "... `&` operator throws an exception". Well, that was specific. Not. Don't you think it might have been useful to tell us _which_ exception up front, including its exact copy-pasted text, if not (portions of) the stack trace? What was your reasoning in support of omitting such key information?

Comment: @Lew Bloch well, all the others could help me without that information, so the problem here is your understanding and, of course, your pedantry. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you from here that the difference between the `&` operator and the `&&` operator is that `&&` will check the first expresion, and if it evaluates to false, then it will simply break from the check, but the `&` operator will run the following expression **regardless of whether or not the first one turned out to be false.**

So, the code you have written will check `(i<(books.size()))`, and whether or not that turns out to be false, `!((books.get(i)).areYouBook(a))` will still be executed.

If however, you used `&&` and `(i<(books.size()))` was false, the second part of your check, which is `!((books.get(i)).areYouBook(a))`, will not be executed.

I hope this helps.

**Edit:**

You mentioned an error being thrown when you used the `&` operator instead of the `&&` operator. Since the `&` operator **does** run the second expression even if the first one is false, I'm wondering if your second expression is actually throwing an error, and is getting called when you use `&`.

**Edit 2:**

Ok. Lets say that `books` has a size of 12 (indexes 0-11) just for demonstration. So, when you use the `&` operator, your while loop runs until `i` is 12. When `i` is 12, the loop executes `(i<(books.size()))` (which returns false) and **CONTINUES** to execute `!((books.get(i)).areYouBook(a))`. Inside the second expression, `books.get(i)` is being called, when `i` is 12. The `books` list only goes from indexes 0-11, throwing a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Thanks, but when I use && the program works perfectly, but if I use &, I get this error message "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)"

Comment: @AilinW.B. Ahh, that makes sense. Let me edit my answer; I see what's going on...

Comment: The error exception is in index 0, which I think it is because the arraylist is empty, right?

Comment: @AilinW.B. Yes. In the error message, "Index" tells you the number that was passed into `get()` and "Size" tells you the size of the array, which is zero.

Answer (score 0):

java [conditional operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) says:

> the operators **&&** and **||** exhibit "short-circuiting" behavior, which means that the second operand is evaluated only if needed.

the logical AND operator `&&`  will be **short-cuircuting** if the left side condition is `false`, on the other hand, when the left side condition is `false` the right side condition is never be executed.

but the [bitwise & operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) performs a bitwise AND operation.

Answer (score -1):

The logical AND that you're trying to use is represented by the && symbol i.e. True && False resolves to False. The single ampersand "&" represents a bitwise AND i.e. 0101 & 0100 resolves to 0110.

Comment: The single ampersand can also be used in place of the double ampersand with a slight change; the single ampersand will always execute the following expression whether or not the first one turns out to be true.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen the single ampersand used that way. Thanks for pointing that out!