# java "&&" operator behaving very strange

Tags: java

I am trying to print a pattern through java. I am using for loop and a conditional statement but there is some problem with && operator. I am  not getting why it is behaving strange with my code specially. Following is my code.

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String ar[]){
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            if((i!=0 && j!=0)){
                System.out.print("*");
            }else{
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

**output**

```
unknown@unknown-Lenovo-E40-80:~/Desktop/java_test$ javac Test.java
unknown@unknown-Lenovo-E40-80:~/Desktop/java_test$ java Test

 ****
 ****
 ****
 ****
```

above output is totally different to my expectation. line 1 is not printed why? i just wanted to skip (i=0 and j=0) location's element.

Comment: `line 1 is not printed` What do you mean? Line 1 is full of spaces.

Comment: What exactly is the operation you want && to do?
Do you know the difference between & and &&? Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-between-and

Comment: Because you could easily come up with the solution, if you would swap the space for another char.

Comment: What pattern do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Let's see what happens:

For line 1 you get `i` = 0  and `j` = 0 to 4, thus you'll get 5 spaces (because `i = 0` will always end up in the result being `false`).
For all other lines `i` is != 0 and `j` is still 0 to 4 so you get 1 space and 4 stars.

If you change the space you print to a underscore you'd get the following output:

```
_____     
_****
_****
_****
_****
```

> i just wanted to skip (i=0 and j=0) location's element

Currently you are skipping all elements that don't have any of their indices being 0 (`i != 0 && j != 0` translates to "`i` is not 0 *and* `j` is not 0").

If you only want to skip that one element you need to either change the expression to `if( i == 0 && j == 0) { skip }` or `if( !(i == 0 && j == 0) ) { do_whatever_you_need }` where the second translates to "if *not* both `i` *and* `j` are 0" (note that this means that either one can be 0, only the combination of both satisfies the condition).

Answer (score 2):

Line 1 is getting printed, but it is printed with spaces.

The reason is because you are checking `(i != 0 && j != 0)`. In the first iteration of the outer loop `i` is 0, hence the control goes to the else block.

Comment: That is not exactly correct. `j` gets incremented, but `i` is still at 0. That's why it gets to the else branch.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean algebra says that !a && !b == !(a || b).  You are trying to say that !a && !b == !(a && b).

Your test of

```
if((i!=0 && j!=0))
```

is equivalent to

```
if(!(i==0 || j == 0))
```

This is not what you want, according to your final statement: *"I just wanted to skip (i=0 and j=0) location's element."*

And so, you can alter your test in a few ways.  The first is probably easiest - reverse the blocks.  This has the fewest operations and is easiest to understand.

```
if (i==0 && j==0)
    System.out.print(" ");
else
    System.out.print("*");
```

Or, if you want to maintain the order, alter your if statement.  To invert your requirement of (i==0 && j==0):  !(a && b) == (!a || !b)

```
if( (i!=0) || (j!=0) )
    System.out.print("*");
else
    System.out.print(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line prints whitespaces, as I added in the comment, because, at this point `i == 0` and prints it 4 times, but the second, third, and others attempts will print  at first because will be equals to zero `j == 0` after that four `*`

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
        if((i!=0 && j!=0)){
            System.out.print("*");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" "); //THIS IS PRINTING THE FIRST LINE
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In first line `i=0` so in first iteration of i control goes to else part and in first row spaces are printed instead of asterisks. And on every iteration of i first index `j=0`.  So again else part executes and in first column again spaces are printed  instead of asterisks. And on all other places asterisks are printed.

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String ar[]){
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                if((i!=0 && j!=0)){
                    System.out.print("*");
                }else{
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```