# efficient computation of haversine distance between elements of collections

Tags: scala

I have two collections. Each collection is comprised of a collection containing a latitude, longitude, and epoch.

```
val arr1= Seq(Seq(34.464, -115.341,1486220267.0), Seq(34.473, 
-115.452,1486227821.0), Seq(35.572, -116.945,1486217300.0), 
Seq(37.843, -115.874,1486348520.0),Seq(35.874, -115.014,1486349803.0), 
Seq(34.345, -116,924, 1486342752.0) )

val arr2= Seq(Seq(35.573, -116.945,1486217300.0 ),Seq(34.853, 
-114.983,1486347321.0 ) )
```

I want to determine how many times the two arrays are within .5 miles and have the same epoch. I have two functions

```
def haversineDistance_single(pointA: (Double, Double), pointB: (Double, Double)): Double = {
  val deltaLat = math.toRadians(pointB._1 - pointA._1)
  val deltaLong = math.toRadians(pointB._2 - pointA._2)
  val a = math.pow(math.sin(deltaLat / 2), 2) + math.cos(math.toRadians(pointA._1)) * math.cos(math.toRadians(pointB._1)) * math.pow(math.sin(deltaLong / 2), 2)
  val greatCircleDistance = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
  3958.761 * greatCircleDistance
    }

def location_time(col_2:Seq[Seq[Double]], col_1:Seq[Seq[Double]]): Int={
  val arr=col_1.map(x=> col_2.filter(y=> (haversineDistance_single((y(0), y(1)), (x(0),x(1)))<=.5) &

    (math.abs(y(2)-x(2))<=0)).flatten).filter(x=> x.length>0)
  arr.length
}


location_time(arr1,arr2) =1
```

My actual collections are very large, is there a more efficient way than my location_time function to compute this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider revising `location_time` from:

```
def location_time(col_mobile: Seq[Seq[Double]], col_laptop: Seq[Seq[Double]]): Int = {
  val arr = col_laptop.map( x => col_mobile.filter( y =>
      (haversineDistance_single((y(0), y(1)), (x(0), x(1))) <= .5) & (math.abs(y(2) - x(2)) <= 0)
    ).flatten
  ).filter(x => x.length > 0)

  arr.length
}
```

to:

```
def location_time(col_mobile: Seq[Seq[Double]], col_laptop: Seq[Seq[Double]]): Int = {
  val arr = col_laptop.flatMap( x => col_mobile.filter( y =>
      ((math.abs(y(2) - x(2)) <= 0 && haversineDistance_single((y(0), y(1)), (x(0), x(1))) <= .5))
    )
  )

  arr.length
}
```

Changes made:

1. Revised `col_mobile.filter(y => ...)` from:

   ```
   filter(_ => costlyCond1 & lessCostlyCond2)
   ```

   to:

   ```
   filter(_ => lessCostlyCond2 && costlyCond1)
   ```

   Assuming `haversineDistance_single` is more costly to run than `math.abs`, replacing `&` with `&&` (see difference between [& versus &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-between-and)) and testing `math.abs` first might help the filtering performance.
2. Simplified `map/filter/flatten/filter` using `flatMap`, replacing:

   ```
   col_laptop.map(x => col_mobile.filter(y => ...).flatten).filter(_.length > 0)
   ```

   with:

   ```
   col_laptop.flatMap( x => col_mobile.filter( y => ... ))
   ```

In case you have access to, say, an Apache Spark cluster, consider converting your collections (if they're really large) to RDDs to compute using transformations similar to the above.