# Java matching 2 strings to exact matches from variables

Tags: java, string, match

I have searched and I cant understand my error.

I have the following

```
while(logincount < 3){
if (tempuser.equals(actualuser) & (temppass.equals(actualpass))
  {
  System.out.println("Success");
  }
else  {
  System.out.println("FAIL");
    logincount=logincount+1;
  }
}
```

And because I cant copy from CMD; http://puu.sh/2svAo the error tells me its expecting a '>'

So I have tried &,&&, and the 2 I cant find the keys for right now.

Thanks, again sorry if this is stupid, I was downvoted to hell in my last question, so I hope this is 'better' ! :-)

Comment: It says ')' expected, not '>'... you don't close the if

Comment: Besides missing a `)` in the `if` line, use `&&` instead of `&`.

Comment: Count your paranthesis. Or even better. Use an editor that does it for you.

Comment: Got it guys thanks, though now its just constantly asking for a user and password!

Comment: instead of while loop i think you need an if statement there

Comment: You just need a break after the success.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if (tempuser.equals(actualuser) & (temppass.equals(actualpass))
```

Has an extra opening bracket, either

```
if (tempuser.equals(actualuser) & temppass.equals(actualpass))
```

or

```
if ((tempuser.equals(actualuser)) & (temppass.equals(actualpass)))
```

should work fine.

Edit: whoops, thanks to dukeling for noticing the typo I made on the last line. (fixed now)

Comment: You're missing 2 closing brackets on the last one, it should be `if ((tempuser.equals(actualuser)) & (temppass.equals(actualpass)))`.

Comment: Thanks working fine now with a combo of your answer and comments above, though cant figure out why my loop wont exit now, haha.

Comment: @T.Des I agree, `&` should almost always be `&&` since `&` won't short circuit, unless that is what he wants.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/differences-in-boolean-operators-vs-and-vs  for any confusion out there.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors there:
1. "(temppass" does need the preceeding "("
2. "&" is a bitwise OR, you need a logical OR here: "&&"

So "if (tempuser.equals(actualuser) & (temppass.equals(actualpass))" becomes "if (tempuser.equals(actualuser) && temppass.equals(actualpass))"

Answer (score 0):

Missing a ")" in the if statement, here is the correction

```
    while(logincount < 3){
        if (tempuser.equals(actualuser) & (temppass.equals(actualpass)))
          {
          System.out.println("Success");
          }
        else  {
          System.out.println("FAIL");
            logincount=logincount+1;
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your code a bit.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (tempuser.equals(actualuser) && temppass.equals(acutalpass)) {
        System.out.println("Success");
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("FAIL");
    }
}
```

1. Use `for` loop instead of `while` loop so that initialization and increment of loop variable is done in one place.
2. Use `&&` instead of `&` for logical `AND`.
3. Add a `break` statement if your password check succeeds.

Comment: I agree, however, slight typo in #2.  && is for logical `AND` not logical `OR`.

Comment: @NickD Great catch! Corrected!