# Bitshift - Need help to understand the code

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am just trying to learn bitwise / shift operations.

I came across the below program but don't understand the AND condition part (checker & (1 << val) in the below program. When will the final Value be greater than 0? Can someone please explain whats happening there?

Sample input:
xyzz

Sample output:

8388608Value 
0checker
0final  value

16777216Value
8388608checker 
0final  value

33554432Value
25165824checker
0final  value

33554432Value
58720256checker
33554432final  value

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
        int checker = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';

            System.out.println((1 << val) + "Value");
            System.out.println((checker) + "checker");
            System.out.println(((checker & (1 << val))) + "final value\n");

            if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                checker = checker | (1 << val);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences in boolean operators: & vs && and | vs ||](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/differences-in-boolean-operators-vs-and-vs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, just to make sure you know what's going on:

`int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';`

Assuming the English alphabet, this is taking the char value for your (lowercase) letter and subtracting 97 (the char value for 'a') to produce a number between 0 and 25 inclusive.  Don't try this function on uppercase characters, you'll get errors unless you add a `.toLowerCase()` after the `.charAt(i)`

`1 << val` is bit-shifting 1 `val` places to the left.  For instance, for 'x' (120 - 97 = 23, so... `1 << 23`), the binary representation would be `00000000010000000000000000000000`

OK, with me so far?

At the start, checker has all 0 bits, so it's `00000000000000000000000000000000`

So... lets put in our numbers instead of our variables.  For our `x` check, `checker & (1 << val)` becomes `00000000000000000000000000000000 & 00000000010000000000000000000000` which equals `00000000000000000000000000000000` because bit 23 isn't set in checker.

So, once `x` is processed, we add bit 23 to checker and move on to the next letter: `y`  This time, `checker & (1 << val)` becomes `00000000010000000000000000000000 & 00000000100000000000000000000000` which equals `00000000000000000000000000000000` because bit 24 isn't set in checker.

For the first `z`, `checker & (1 << val)` becomes `00000000110000000000000000000000 & 00000001000000000000000000000000` which equals `00000000000000000000000000000000` because bit 25 isn't set in checker.

For the second `z`, `checker & (1 << val)` becomes `00000001110000000000000000000000 & 00000001000000000000000000000000` which equals `00000001000000000000000000000000` (decimal 33554432 or 2^25) because bit 25 **is** set in checker, therefore the `> 0` is now `true` and the function returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what your function does is check if all characters in the input string are different. It returns false iff the same (lower case) character appears more than once.

The `checker` variable serves as a kind of bit map that accumulates which characters have appeared so far. Data type `int` consists of 32 bits which is enough to assign one bit per each character (26).

The function loops over all characters of str. The row `int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';` assigns some sort of ordinal value to `val` depending on the character ('a' => 0, 'b' => 1, 'c' => 2, etc.).

The expression `1 << val` assigns each val in the range of (0..25) to its bit position. Therefore, character 'a' is mapped to 1 << 0 == 1 == 00000001, character 'd' is mapped 1 << 3 == 00001000, and so on. Each character is assigned its unique bit mask with exactly one bit set and all other bits cleared.

The expression `(checker & (1 << val))` is > 0 exactly iff the bit that is set in `1 << val` is also set in checker (note that checker might have more than one bit set). If so, the currently iterated character has appeared earlier, and the function returns false. Otherwise, the bit mask of the current character is added via bitwise OR operator `|` to the checker that acts as an accumulator. If all characters have been looped over and no character has been met twice, the function returns true. Note that the function might ignore upper-case and other characters.