# Detailed explanation for Bit wise or Operator works in different method

Tags: java, operators, bitwise-operators

Here the code.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x=2; int y = 3;
        if((y == x++) | (x < ++y)){
            System.out.println("x = " + x + "Y = " + y);
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs `x=3 y=4`

Another Criteria

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(4|3);
    }
}
```

This outputs `7`

Here the second criteria `|` works as bit wise operator.  But in first criteria `|` is not.  It manipulates and giving the output.  I need explanation how the first criteria works.

The thing i know is, `|`  will compare both sides and `||` will compare only left side and it true it proceeds to next.

Hope my question is clear.  Thankyou in advance..

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Comment: I went to one interview today and the second criteria was asked there.  I marked 0 as answer by thinking no proper boolean experession.   After reaching home this makes me confused.  How this operator can take two work.  bit wise or and or operations.

Comment: Also see [Differences in boolean operators: & vs && and | vs ||](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/differences-in-boolean-operators-vs-and-vs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [JLS 15.22.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2):

> When both operands of a `&`, `^`, or `|` operator are of type `boolean` or `Boolean`, then the type of the bitwise operator expression is `boolean`. In all cases, the operands are subject to unboxing conversion ([§5.1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) as necessary.
>
> For `&`, the result value is `true` if both operand values are `true`; otherwise, the result is `false`.
>
> For `^`, the result value is `true` if the operand values are different; otherwise, the result is `false`.
>
> For `|`, the result value is `false` if both operand values are `false`; otherwise, the result is `true`.

Take the first case:

```
int x=2; int y = 3;
if((y == x++) | (x < ++y)){
       System.out.println("x = " + x + "Y = " + y);
}
```

`(y == x++)` is false because `x++` is post-increment , `(x < ++y)` is true , hence `false|true` is `true` and you get the console o/p with the values of `x=3` and `y=4`.

---

Second case , is natural bitwise OR :

```
System.out.println(4|3);
```

That in *3-bits* is  `(011|100)` = `(111)` = `7`(base 10).

Comment: Very nice explanation buddy.  Thankyou.  Now i can understand how it works.  Any how it is taking boolean values as it operands and manipulates.

Answer (score 2):

For the first example you will have:

```
if ((3 == 2) | (3 < 4))
```

which is equal to:

```
if ( false | true )
```

and evaluates to `true` (since the both sides of the expression are compared).

For the second example, since you already know that `|` will compare both sides, here's what it really happens. The numbers are converted into binary ones and then the operation is applied:

```
4 | 3
```

will be converted to:

```
100 | 011 = 111
```

which is equal to `7`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, first the left side of the expression is evaluated:

```
y == x++ // y == x; x=x + 1
```

`y` is 3, x is 2, the equality check is `false`, and the `x` is incremented to 3.

and then the right side of the expression is evaluated:

```
x < ++y; // y = y + 1; x < y
```

`y` is incremented and is 4, and then is checked if `x` is smaller than `y`. And yes, 3 is smaller than 4, and the result of the right part is `true`.

Since there is bitwise `|` operator between `false` on the left side and `true` on the right side, the result is

```
false | true = true
```

And that's why the expression is `true` and `syso` is executed.

---

In the second example, a bitwise OR is executed, hence

```
100 | 011 = 111 //is equal to 7
```