# If statement that uses 3 boolean values

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

Im trying to make an if statement like this:

```
if(boolean1 AND boolean2 AND boolean3 == true){
   [Do this....]
}
```

is there a way to do an if statement in that format or will i have to do it like this:

```
if(boolean1 = true & boolean2 = true ect...){}
```

Comment: btw: if you're in a boolean context, you never need to compare it to `== true`, and probably never should (it's just noise). So, don't do `if (a && b && c == true)`, just do `if (a && b && c)`.

Comment: Also note that a single & does a bitwise and instead of a logical one. Using & when you really mean && can range from a small performance hit to disaster, depending on the instance.

Comment: would not recommend it but `if (Stream.of(boolean1, boolean2, boolean3).allMatch(Boolean.TRUE::equals))` has semantics close to what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Least you can get is

```
if(boolean1 && boolean2 && boolean3 &&..){

}
```

Because since they are already booleans you need not to check for their value. Afaik, no other simple way.

If you have toooooooo many, create an array and write a simple util method to check if any is `false`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you need two `&`(s) for logical and (one is a bitwise and). Also, one equals is assignment (you need two, or none). Something like,

```
if (boolean1 && boolean2 && boolean3){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Actually you don't _need_ the double `&´ (bitwise AND works fine). Though sometimes more efficient.

Comment: That said, `&&` is much more common, so if a peer comes across a single-`&`, they're likely to assume it's a typo and fix it for you. If you really do want single-`&` for some reason, it's probably worth adding a comment in the code.

Comment: They are not the same: the single & will check both conditions always, the double && will stop after the first condition if it evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to compare with `true` (though sometimes that can be nice for readability):

```
if (boolean1 && boolean2 && boolean3) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax that will work in quite in the fashion of checking three variables or statements against a single outcome. It's important to note that `&&` and `&` as logical operators do not match all normal uses of the word AND (for instance, you could not check that `boolean1 AND boolean2 AND boolean3 == false` with `&&` or `&` operators).

That said, evaluating `boolean1 == true` will give the same result as just `boolean1`. So the tedious if statement

```
if(boolean1 == true & boolean2 == true & boolean3 == true){...}
```

can be shortened to

```
if(boolean1 & boolean2 & boolean3){...}
```

It is also probably advisable to use `&&` instead of `&` unless you have a specific reason to avoid short-circuiting. See [Differences in boolean operators: & vs && and | vs ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/differences-in-boolean-operators-vs-and-vs) for more on that topic.