# Java Strange behavior checking loop-conditions

Tags: while-loop, nullpointerexception, conditional-statements

I have this:

```
while(victim.getHealth() > 1 && !victim.getName().equals(this.getName())) {
    victim.hurt();
}
```

Now I noticed that in special occasions victim.getName() will return null (this is wanted behavior). But when that's the case I am expecting a NullPointerException to occur because we are basically calling null.equals(this.getName()) for the second condition.

However this doesn't happen. If I switch the order of the loop-conditions, e.g.

```
while(!victim.getName().equals(this.getName()) && victim.getHealth() > 1) {
    victim.hurt();
}
```

The NullPointerException will be thrown when getName() returns null.

Also: If this was || condition and not &&, in java the programm will stop checking for true condition once it found one right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/differences-in-boolean-operators-vs-and-vs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice that in this special case where getName() == null victim.getHealth() will always be below 1 so java will never reach the second condition. Sorry I need a break now. :D